# grouping partners in two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset like this:

```
A B
---
a a1
a a2
a a3
.
.
.
z z1
z z2
z z3
z z4
.
.
```

Now for each unique value in Column A, I want a random partner of that value from column B.

Example:

```
a,a3
b,b54
c,c33
d,d77
```

Is there anyway this can be done using pandas or by using csv stream in python in an efficient and fast manner?

Comment: do you mean actually random - or just a matching algorithm that you haven't specified?

Comment: Is it iid random in the sense that there can be duplicates on the right hand side, or do items get removed from the pool once they're matched to `A`?

Comment: select all uniques from A and for all uniques, find 'any one' random partner from B.

Comment: is it a pandas dataset or a file or where is it coming from?

Comment: For the future, given the number of questions in the comments, you can tell that this is a quite sloppily asked question. A bit surprising for a user with such high reputation. Next time, please provide a reproducable dataframe and be explicit on what you exactly desire.

Comment: Well, you didnt understand the problem and thats why you feel so. I will edit it and put a better explaination

Answer (score 2):

Group by column A, and select a random value for "B" from the corresponding group.

```
df.groupby("A").agg({"B": lambda x: random.choice(x)})
```

Comment: I think he wants it independent from the group. Select a unique value of `A`, and group with random value of `B` drawn from whole column.

Comment: oh in that case, random.choice should be called upon all values of B i.e. df["B"].values

Comment: No. I dont want it independent from the group. @AnkushShah is right!

Answer (score 0):

Most standard I could think of: Create new dataframe with uniques, sample from old dataframe.

```
import random
import pandas as pd

df2 = df.drop_duplicates('A')
indices = random.sample(df.index, len(df2))
df2['B'] = df.loc[indices, 'B'].values
```

Answer (score -1):

probably a better way of doing it but

```
import random as rd
import pandas as pd

a = ['a1','a2','a3']
b=['b1','b2','b3']
rd.shuffle(b)

print pd.DataFrame([a,b])
```

Comment: You're not starting from a dataframe. You also don't check for uniques. Finally, you're just rematching - he mentioned that he wants an independent draw for every row.